# How to make Google extension options page in the toolbar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Recently, I've started learning how to make Google Chrome extensions. My problem is that I don't know how to make a button in the toolbar so that when I click on it, it show me options for my extension like this example:

[image]

I can get the icon of my extension to appear in the toolbar, but nothing happens when I click on it.  Here is my `manifest.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "Extension Name",
    "version": "0.1.1.2",
    "description": "Extension's description",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "background": {
        "page": "index.html"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "name": "Manipulate DOM",
        "icons": {
            "128":"icon.png"
        },
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "js-resource.js" ],
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: That's not an options page but a popup page, see [Getting Started: Building a Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).

Comment: FYI, the link to `options.html` shows up when you go to `chrome://extensions` under your extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm Would you _please_ stop answering in comments? (however, looking at your totally 1337 reputation, I can understand..)

Comment: @Xan, I thought it's not an answer as the question itself didn't seem valid to me - no research.

Comment: @Garrett Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 1):

That's a [popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups), not an options page. Currently you have two ways to do an options page as such:

- [Old way: In a separated tab.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options)
- [New way (Chrome 40 onwards): In a popup in the extensions page.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2)

  [image: Chrome extension options page V2]

However, those page are not too special and the only thing you should do to persist the user's preferences is to store them in `chrome.storage.sync`, as you can read in both links, respectively:

> Use the `storage.sync` API to persist these preferences. These values will then become accessible in any script within your extension, on all your user's devices.
>
> Always use the `storage.sync` API to persist your options. This will make them accessible from script within your extension, on all of your user's devices.

So as long as you store the preferences in there, you can make an options page in the browser action (or page action) popup. You just need to add the following to your `manifest.json` and to create the `popup.html` page:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_title":    "Manipulate DOM",
    "default_icon":     "icon.png",
    "default_popup":    "popup.html",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They changed it in manifest 3 so instead of the original method it is now `"action":{ "default_popup": "popup.html"   }`
If you want to read more go [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/user-interface)